# Does a function like this already exist? (Or, what's a better name for this function?)

Tags: haskell, monads, idioms

I've written code with the following pattern several times recently, and was wondering if there was a shorter way to write it.

```
foo :: IO String
foo = do
    x <- getLine
    putStrLn x >> return x
```

To make things a little cleaner, I wrote this function (though I'm not sure it's an appropriate name):

```
constM :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> a -> m a
constM f a = f a >> return a
```

I can then make foo like this:

```
foo = getLine >>= constM putStrLn
```

Does a function/idiom like this already exist?  And if not, what's a better name for my constM?

Comment: It seems that you can define this function using plain functors: `constF :: Functor f => (a -> f b) -> a -> f a; constF f a = a <$ f a`

Comment: @FUZxxl, this does work as well, thanks... is this correct usage of the const name then?

Comment: @FUZxxl, I'm not quite sure I understand how things are named in FP.  Just wanted to be sure the name isn't misleading.  It looks a bit like const, except I am using the 'a' here in the function I supply, that's why I was uncertain.

Comment: I guess the name is good. PS: You can make the definition even shorter: `constF = ap (<$)` Than you can inline it: `foo = getLine >>= (<$) <*> putStrLn`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, let's consider the ways that something like this *could* be simplified. A non-monadic version would I guess look something like `const' f a = const a (f a)`, which is clearly equivalent to `flip const` with a more specific type. With the monadic version, however, the result of `f a` can do arbitrary things to the non-parametric structure of the functor (i.e., what are often called "side effects"), including things that depend on the value of `a`. What this tells us is that, despite *pretending* like we're discarding the result of `f a`, we're actually doing nothing of the sort. Returning `a` unchanged as the parametric part of the functor is far less essential, and we could replace `return` with something else and still have a conceptually similar function.

So the first thing we can conclude is that it can be seen as a special case of a function like the following:

```
doBoth :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> (a -> m c) -> a -> m c
doBoth f g a = f a >> g a
```

From here, there are two different ways to look for an underlying structure of some sort.

---

One perspective is to recognize the pattern of **splitting a single argument among multiple functions, then recombining the results**. This is the concept embodied by the `Applicative`/`Monad` instances for functions, like so:

```
doBoth :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> (a -> m c) -> a -> m c
doBoth f g = (>>) <$> f <*> g
```

...or, if you prefer:

```
doBoth :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> (a -> m c) -> a -> m c
doBoth = liftA2 (>>)
```

Of course, `liftA2` is equivalent to `liftM2` so you might wonder if lifting an operation on monads into another monad has something to do with monad transformers; in general the relationship there is awkward, but in this case it works easily, giving something like this:

```
doBoth :: (Monad m) => ReaderT a m b -> ReaderT a m c -> ReaderT a m c
doBoth = (>>)
```

...modulo appropriate wrapping and such, of course. To specialize back to your original version, the original use of `return` now needs to be something with type `ReaderT a m a`, which shouldn't be too hard to recognize as the `ask` function for reader monads.

---

The other perspective is to recognize that functions with types like `(Monad m) => a -> m b` **can be composed directly, much like pure functions**. The function `(<=<) :: Monad m => (b -> m c) -> (a -> m b) -> (a -> m c)` gives a direct equivalent to function composition `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)`, or you can instead make use of `Control.Category` and the `newtype` wrapper `Kleisli` to work with the same thing in a generic way.

We still need to split the argument, however, so what we really need here is a "branching" composition, which `Category` alone doesn't have; by using `Control.Arrow` as well we get `(&&&)`, letting us rewrite the function as follows:

```
doBoth :: (Monad m) => Kleisli m a b -> Kleisli m a c -> Kleisli m a (b, c)
doBoth f g = f &&& g
```

Since we don't care about the result of the first Kleisli arrow, only its side effects, we can discard that half of the tuple in the obvious way:

```
doBoth :: (Monad m) => Kleisli m a b -> Kleisli m a c -> Kleisli m a c
doBoth f g = f &&& g >>> arr snd
```

Which gets us back to the generic form. Specializing to your original, the `return` now becomes simply `id`:

```
constKleisli :: (Monad m) => Kleisli m a b -> Kleisli m a a
constKleisli f = f &&& id >>> arr snd
```

Since regular functions are also `Arrow`s, the definition above works there as well if you generalize the type signature. However, it may be enlightening to expand the definition that results for pure functions and simplify as follows:

- `\f x -> (f &&& id >>> arr snd) x`
- `\f x -> (snd . (\y -> (f y, id y))) x`
- `\f x -> (\y -> snd (f y, y)) x`
- `\f x -> (\y -> y) x`
- `\f x -> x`.

So we're back to `flip const`, as expected!

---

In short, your function is some variation on either `(>>)` or `flip const`, but in a way that relies on the differences--the former using both a `ReaderT` environment and the `(>>)` of the underlying monad, the latter using the implicit side-effects of the specific `Arrow` and the expectation that `Arrow` side effects happen in a particular order. Because of these details, there's not likely to be any generalization or simplification available. In some sense, the definition you're using is exactly as simple as it needs to be, which is why the alternate definitions I gave are longer and/or involve some amount of wrapping and unwrapping.

A function like this would be a natural addition to a "monad utility library" of some sort. While `Control.Monad` provides some combinators along those lines, it's far from exhaustive, and I could neither find nor recall any variation on this function in the standard libraries. I would not be at all surprised to find it in one or more utility libraries on hackage, however.

Having mostly dispensed with the question of existence, I can't really offer much guidance on naming beyond what you can take from the discussion above about related concepts.

As a final aside, note also that your function has no control flow choices based on the result of a monadic expression, since executing the expressions no matter what is the main goal. Having a computational structure independent of the parametric content (i.e., the stuff of type `a` in `Monad m => m a`) is usually a sign that you don't actually need a full `Monad`, and could get by with the more general notion of `Applicative`.

Comment: Not an answer to his question.  +1 anyway for great analysis.  :-)

Comment: @luqui: Well, it was intended to be a sort of round-about explanation of looking for underlying structure in order to find generalizations of something, given that the *exact* function described doesn't exist... but yeah, that sort of got lost somewhere along the way. Should probably revise this a bit at some point to make that clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, I don't think `constM` is appropriate here.

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
mapM :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m b

const :: b -> a -> b
```

So perhaps:

```
constM :: (Monad m) => b -> m a -> m b
constM b m = m >> return b
```

The function you are `M`-ing seems to be:

```
f :: (a -> b) -> a -> a
```

Which has no choice but to ignore its first argument.  So this function does not have much to say purely.

I see it as a way to, hmm, *observe* a value with a *side effect*.  `observe`, `effect`, `sideEffect` may be decent names.  `observe` is my favorite, but maybe just because it is catchy, not because it is clear.

Comment: I think observe is clearer than my name, and I guess it doesn't need an 'M' since a pure equivalent to this wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: I'm dubious about `observe`. We certainly don't observe the value produced by the function, and since the function requires only `Applicative` we'll not necessarily be observing any side effects either.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really have a clue this exactly allready exists, but you see this a lot in parser-generators only with different names (for example to get the *thing* inside brackets) - there it's normaly some kind of operator (`>>.` and `.>>` in fparsec for example) for this. To really give a name I would maybe call it **ignore**?

Comment: I've seen people use the name `ignore` for `ignore :: Monad m => m a -> m ()`, `ignore m = m >> return ()`.

Comment: @Judah To surpress the warning about discarding the result of a do-statement?

Comment: I'm not sure ignore is correct since I require the given value be returned.

Comment: @FUZxxl That's one use; another is for functions like `forkIO` that expect a `()` return value.

Comment: yeah - that's why I put the *?* in there - I thought **ignore** because it basically ignores what ``f`` is doing (besides it's sideeffects of course ;) ) ... but your are all right the version Judah has given is surely more fitting to be called *ignore* - what about `sideeffectsOnly``? :D

Comment: @AdamWagner I agree, I just wanted to point out that the name `ignore` has been used for a different purpose in the past.

Comment: that makes sense, and it is quite similar to ignore.. maybe I'm using patterns not typical to haskell/fp, and that is why I find I need this?  Btw, one of my uses of this is with forkIO.

Comment: I sometimes define `ignore a b = b`.

Comment: Haskell already has (>>.) and (.>>) - as (<*) and (*>) respectively. It trips me up to no end that I have to flip around the angle brackets between languages.

Answer (score 0):

There's `interact`:

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/haskell98/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:interact

It's not quite what you're asking for, but it's similar.

Comment: He also want's to return the result; `interact` can't do this. I guess, he just wanted to explain the functionality he wants by a simple example. Your answer is not very helpful.